# Toolbar scrolls down in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm having a problem scrolling with the CoordinatorLayout, see gif

[See amazing gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0PhO.gif)

I think the problem is using the translucentStatus with the toolbar padding-top, how can i fix it ?
I already tried using a custom ScrollingViewBehavior, but it didn't work :(

Thanks for the help, in advance

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="24dp" />

        <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:pstsShouldExpand="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<im.tox.toktok.app.view.widgets.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:insetForeground="#4000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/drawer_accent_color"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:elevation="2dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/drawer_accent_color"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-48dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_user_logo"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@color/light_grey" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
                    android:text="André Almeida"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_larger" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="This is a sample message that crosses…"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_small" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</im.tox.toktok.app.view.widgets.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

to your CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: If i use that, it pushes the toolbar down, and the statusbar doesn't have the background color that i need, like this -> [link](http://i.imgur.com/pbXZPVD.png)

Comment: How is your theme defined ? Have you defined :         <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item> 
in your v21 style? And what's the framelayout after the corrindator layout ? Your posted xml is not correct and will not compile , cause you have 2 root elements.

Comment: I have the normal structure of the android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout [check here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: This is not a 'normal' drawer layout.